# Right option key of an external keyboard not working

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, ventura

I use my MacOS (with Ventura) with 2 different external keyboards. On the first, all runs smoothly. On the second, a [Logitech K120](https://www.logitech.com/it-ch/products/keyboards/k120-usb-standard-computer.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMImv-o6rer_AIVRqjVCh21TgomEAAYAiAAEgLti_D_BwE) with an ISO-IT layout, the right option key doesn't work at all.

Here is my modifier mapping:

[image]

I wouldn't like to use external software to remap keys. As I mentioned, my first keyboard is working fine and I do not want to break its functionalities.

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

Most Windows keyboards don't have a 'right Option' Key. Instead they send AltGr, which is interpreted as Ctrl + Alt pressed simultaneously.

The Mac cannot then differentiate it from truly pressing  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  +  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd> .

It may be possible to remap this in [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org), though I'm not familiar with its operation.

Comment: I see. Will this affect also the behavior of the other external keyboard?

Comment: idk whether Karabiner can target a specific keyboard, but if the other is an Apple or equivalent, it won't be sending AltGr in the first place, so there's nothing to remap.

Comment: btw, even if I swap back CMD and Option in the mapping, the AltGr key works properly as an Option Key, the right-CMD doesn't work at all again.

Comment: Windows keyboards don't have a Cmd key, though the Windows key [on the left] is usually translated as one. I've never seen one on the right. There's sometimes a Menu key, but idk how that's interpreted, if at all.